# iterate through string array

Tags: php, arrays

For my code:
            `var_dump($POS);`

gives me:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => string 'technical' (length=9)
  1 => string 'recruiter' (length=9)
  2 => string 'experience' (length=10)
  3 => string 'work' (length=4)
  4 => string 'department' (length=10)
  5 => string 'modern' (length=6)
  6 => string 'age' (length=3)
  7 => string 'profile' (length=7)
  8 => string 'prakhar' (length=7)
```

But while Iterate through array `$POS`

```
        foreach($POS as $p)
        {
            echo "POS  :".$p."<br/>";
        }
```

it echos only first value i.e. `technical`

What is wrong?

Actual code:

```
    function getTag($post)
    {
            $tagger = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt');
            $temp = $tagger->tag($post);
            $POS = getPOS($temp);
            //var_dump($POS);
            //$POS = implode(", ",$POS);
            $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');                
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                return;
            }

            $selectTag = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT distinct tag from koove_tags");
            $i = 0;
            $totalPOSs = '';
            $POSs = '';
            $distinctPOSs = '';
            //$prob[$i] = new stdClass();

                    //calculate distinct POS in all POSs for all tags
                    $selectPOS3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pos from koove_posts");
                    while ($row4 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectPOS3))
                    {

                        $distinctPOSs.=$row4['pos'].",";        
                    }

                    $distinct_pos_Count = count(array_unique(str_word_count($distinctPOSs, 1))); 
                    //var_dump($distinctPOSs);
                    //echo "Distinv pos:".$distinct_pos_Count.'<br/> ';
            var_dump($POS);
            foreach($POS as $p)
            {
                echo "POS  :".$p."<br/>";
                while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
                {
                    //Calculate total pos for given tag
                    //echo "Tag : ".$row1['tag']."<br/>";
                    $selectPOS1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from koove_posts where tag = '".$row1['tag']."'");
                    $totalPOSs = '';
                    while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectPOS1))
                    {
                        //echo $row2['pos']."<br/>";
                        $totalPOSs.=$row2['pos'].",";       
                    }
                    $totalPOS_count = str_word_count($totalPOSs);
                    //echo "Totla POS fo tag ".$row1['tag']." is ".$totalPOS_count."<br/>";

                    //calculate how many times particular 'pos' appears for given tag
                    //echo $totalPOSs."<br/>";
                    echo "pos : ".$p."<br/>";
                    $pos_Count = substr_count($totalPOSs, $p);

                    //echo "POS count for POS ".$p." and  tag ".$row1['tag']." is ".$pos_Count."<br/>";

                    //Calculate the probability for each part of speach
                    $prob[] = (object) array(
                        "value" => ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count),
                        "tag"   => $row1['tag'],
                        );
                        }               
            }
}
```

**UPDATE**

loop for `$POS` is fine but issue is with

```
while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
                { 

}
```

Because what I noticed, For first part of speech above `while` loop executed correctly, but for next `$POS` it does not.

Do I need to flush/clear `$row1`?

Comment: Please, provide minimal code which reproduces the issue (full code with array definition)

Comment: Do you run any function between those 2 calls?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: no, I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

Try to comment everything in loop (leave only echo) and you will have all values in your array.

You should also add at the beginning of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

(only when testing) and remove `@` in front of `mysqli_fetch_array` to have displayed all errors